# How to change styling of cells that has been edited in ag-Grid?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I want to mark cells who has been edited so the user can see which cells have been touched and altered. I know there is a cell flash option, but that just changes the background colors for a bit. What I want is a background color change when an edit has been done.

Cannot seem to find any specific documentation on accessing for example the html element or the styling of affected cell.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ColDef.onCellValueChanged` to detect if something changes and update the cell style accordingly using `GridApi.refreshCells()`

```js
const columnDefs = [{
  headerName: "Athlete",
  field: "athlete",
  onCellValueChanged: this.markAsDirty
},...]

...

private markAsDirty(params: ICellRendererParams) {
  params.colDef.cellClass = (p) =>
    p.rowIndex.toString() === params.node.id ? "ag-cell-dirty" : "";

  params.api.refreshCells({
    columns: [params.column.getId()],
    rowNodes: [params.node],
    force: true // without this line, the cell style is not refreshed at the first time
  });
}
```

### In your css file

```css
:host ::ng-deep .ag-cell-dirty {
  background-color: rgba(255, 193, 7, 0.5) !important;
}
```

You may also want to use `defaultColDef` if you want this behavior applied to all columns

```js
this.gridOptions = {
  defaultColDef: {
    editable: true,
    onCellValueChanged: this.markAsDirty
  },
};
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit AgGrid Mark Dirty On Editing]

Answer (score -1):

I did this on a project I was working on.

There is a `cellClass` property that you can define in your column definitions (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styles/) and it can take a callback function with `params: CellClassParams`.

So try doing:

```
cellClass: (params: CellClassParams) => {
  // you need to have a handle on the original untouched data
  // See if the original value does not equal the modified value in params
  // For shortness, I will write pseudocode
   if (originalValue !== modifiedValue) {
     return 'ag-cell-was-modified';
   }
}
```

If many columns are editable, you may want to use a re-usable function for `cellClass` for each column.

That should apply the class `ag-cell-was-modified` conditionally whether the cell was modified or not and in your style.scss or main stylesheet, you can add:

```
.ag-cell-was-modified {
  background: red;
}
```

Of course, if you are using SASS, you can place this class definition in somewhere more appropriate.

Comment: How you do this: "you need to have a handle on the original untouched data" ??

Comment: Have an instance variable called originalData and assign to it the data that is initially going into the grid. Then when `cellClass` is called, on the params you will get the new value and I assume there is an id on it. Find this value by id in the originalData and see if the value is different than what came in params. This may not be the most efficient and if you want to do this, you should consider the accepted answer's approach.